# Fundamental questions about multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

> **I was curious if this is allow syntax and if it is what exactly it does:**

```
public void startThreads(string userIp){
     user1 = new TCPListener("0.0.0.0", 1111);
     tmpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => User1Listern(user1);
     tmpThread.Start();

     user2 = new TCPListener("0.0.0.0", 1112);
     tmpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => User2Listern(user2);
     tmpThread.Start();

     user3 = new TCPListener("0.0.0.0", 1113);
     tmpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => User3Listern(user3);
     tmpThread.Start();
}

public void User3Listern(TCPListener tmp){
    tcpLister = (TCPListener)tmp;
    user3.Start(); //Start User3 
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //MS documenation
    while(true){
        user3 = this.tcpListener.AccepTcpClient();
        Thread User3Start = new Thread(new ParamertizedThreadStart(User3Profile));
        User3Start.Start(user3);
    }    
}
```

> **My Questions:**

- Is can a thread contain multiple threads like that? (tmpThread)
- what happens if you dont 'Join' these you just "start" them.

Answer (score 2):

> can a thread contain multiple threads like that?

That's not what's happening.  These threads aren't being "joined" in any way.  Each one is being created and started, one at a time.

When you do this:

```
tmpThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => User2Listern(user2);
```

The new thread has nothing to do with the previous thread.  What's happening here doesn't even really have anything to do with threads, the same would be true for any object.

A new object is being created, and the variable now points to that new object instead of the old one.  The old one still exists.  If nothing is using the old object then it may be available for garbage collection under the hood.  But that's not the case here, the old object is still in memory and still doing its thing as a thread.  The *variable* simply points to a new object now.

If, at the end of this method, you examine the contents of `tmpThread` you'll find that it references only the last `Thread` object that was created.  This method no longer has any references to the first two objects.

Comment: So really each UserThread should be a whole new thread? And then join them? back to the master thread? Because I want to be listening for changes any anytime from any of the users

Comment: @SetupG: I'm not sure what you're asking there.  Each thread is created and started, one by one.  None of the three threads created appear to have anything to do with each other.

Comment: Will they listen throughout the program then? If say User1's listener get triggered then user2's does. How does it determine which one to execute. Why or why not would I want to join them or not.

Comment: @SetupG: From the code shown it would appear that methods like `User1Listern` and the others will be listenting for TCP connections on specific ports.  Any connections to those ports should be observable in those methods, handled within their respective threads.  Are those methods not doing what you expect?  Is there a specific problem you're observing?

Comment: Yes, its strange because I can verify on the user's side we are sending the correct data over but it is only getting some not all of the messages. Because the users will respond in groups possibly. For example I have user1 and user2 sending back I'm seeing in the same loop oh user1 user1 user2 user2 user1. But It may not even be the right data (sending over byte arrays). If I put a sleep on the users side it works fine.

Comment: I added in the listener. @David

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with couple of fundamental concepts, which you have skipped:

- Code that you have posted is an obsolete by current C#.Net standard, no more are Thread API used as you have posted, as of now everything is done using `Parallel` API, which internally utilize the `Threadpool`

> **What are Threads ?**

- Windows is a Multi threaded OS, unlike Linux, which is Multi process, threads in general are nothing but simple set of execution instructions.
- On a multi core system, multiple such instructions can be executed per core, thus multiple threads / process.
- Thread is thus nothing but logical unit and lightweight execution context
- Now every process in windows have a Main thread and it has the ability to also summon other threads (back ground threads  or thread pool threads) to do other tasks in Background, which has multiple usage like making processing faster (Parallelism - CPU / IO bound)
- Main thread is a foreground thread and pool threads are always background. Background threads cannot exist without main / foreground thread, since process executing it will go off with Main thread.

> **Now your code and what it does ?**

- You are initiating three background threads, where you are supplying delegate as expected by the constructor.
- As in case of 3rd thread, you are probably passing the TCPListener on each thread to listen to the incoming TCP request.
- All threads are initiated on the Main thread and they start executing in the background

> **My Question is can a thread contain multiple threads like that? (tmpThread)?**

- As I have clarified, this is not one thread containing multiple threads, but just that back ground threads are executed on calling `start` method, when summoned by the Main thread and then control goes back to the main thread, while back ground threads finish their tasks in the background.

> **what happens if you don't 'Join' these you just "start" them.**

- `Join` is an indication to the main thread to wait for back ground thread to finish before exiting, if join is not called, then main thread may exit, if it has nothing to process, thus the process would finish and background thread then are like zombies, no result is possible via them. Though mostly this is the case if the back ground thread is executing some in memory job, let's assume it made a DB call, then that would go through, but no result will return if expected, since there's no thread available to receive them

> **Some more information**

- Looking at your Thread3 code, where you have infinite loop, it may overwhelm the system, please remember threads are costly resource
- Using thread pool via Parallel API does much better optimization, it never over provision and doesn't overwhelm the system
- Only issue with multiple threads is race condition and deadlocks, for which various synchronization context like lock, semaphore are available
- For multi threading design concurrent collections are a better choice

> **Edit 1**

Review the TCP server implementation on the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZEjICp), i have used the reference from the following [link](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233470-tcplistener-and-tcpclient-an-easy-to-use-example-part-2).

> What does the implementation contains:

1. Async TCP server is implemented, which awaits in the background to receive the I/p
2. Once the Input is received, the its processed, as shown in the method `DoSomethingWithClientAsync()`
3. Since implementation is Async you can start 1000s of TCP server, without any impact on the system, since there's no background thread blocking
4. Main thread will await the background process to complete
5. Each server shall start at the unique port

Comment: Very useful information. Do you happen to have time to show an example or link to MS on how to do such?

Comment: Also worth noting is it standard practice of have the TCPListener have it's own thread? Just seems like a lot of threads that aren't needed.

Comment: Detail your exact use case, I will try to post the example code, current question is not very clear in terms of use case, it is more of threading question. As far as tcp listener is concerned, it's good to execute on background / worker thread, since you may not want to block main thread doing  it, that will freeze the process, infact ui would become unresponsive, since main thread is blocked waiting

Comment: I am trying to send configuration between the users, and the main guy (server sorta say) is where this code is from. Then inside of each of the users they have their own socket connection they are listening to incoming data. Once the change has been made the user sends off the acknowledgement with the changed value.

Comment: Why would you have threads in a process represent a user, which needs to listen to the TCP incoming message, this kind of solution just cannot scale up, since you cannot keep spawning the threads, this is an ideal requirement for background thread pool, where Async requests can be executed without blocking, while the request is awaited, the pool thread will not be blocked. 
Your use case is ideal for `Async-Await` usage.

Comment: Check the `Edit1`, where I have added the .Net Fiddle, which implements the TCP server using the Async await, this is a highly scalable code, due to its non blocking nature